# Connections to multiple ssh servers freezing

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, ssh, freeze

I am trying to connect to two SSH servers running on two separate Ubuntu OS from a Windows PC. The login goes okay in most cases on both terminals but after login the last connected terminal almost always freezes, and in some cases never wakes up again.

I have tried several different Windows clients (PuTTY, SmarTTY, MobaXterm) but with the same result. The connections are passing through a gigabit switch.

The connection is fine with only a single connection.

Does anyone have any idea of what is going wrong here?

Comment: Update NIC drivers? Give that a shot. It looks like to me that the Windows host is clearly the problem.

Comment: I have updated the NIC driver but the result is unfortunately still the same...

Comment: Retry with your firewall disabled

Comment: I have tried that as well. I have tried to narrow down the problem further: I can ping the Linux computers individually without any problems but when I try to ping them simultaneously it almost always fails for one of the connections but it seems quite random which one will fail. It seems as if the switch only allows one data stream at a time. Could that be the case?

Comment: This may be a stupid question but is the driver for your NIC set to half duplex? In `devmgmt.msc` right click on the NIC and go Properties, under "Speed & Duplex", is the value `Auto Negotiation`?

Comment: Yes, it is set to Auto Negotiation. The Ubuntu systems are embedded computers, so yes - physical hosts. Can that be a problem for the network adapter?

Comment: Are you virtualising these Ubuntu systems or are they physical hosts? If so, the network adapter type may be an issue. Please confirm what hypervisor you are using if you are virtualising.

Comment: The Ubuntu systems are physical systems...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by identical MAC address on the Linux systems. Changing to unique MAC addresses solved the problem.